# iPhone: Saving picture/data to "public" folder?

Tags: iphone, backup, directory

I want to implement a backup feature in the app I'm working on, that simply puts an image and some data in a folder that can be accessed through itunes or similar.

But is this possible, and what can be done?

Point of the feature is that if (for some reason) the image and data isn't sent to my server, the user will have the ability to extract it to a pc/mac, so that the image and data isn't lost.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabled iTunes file sharing in your app's settings and then write your file to the Documents folder in your app.  This will then allow them to see the file through iTunes.